# AnimateVectorDrawableCompat seems to need valueFrom and valueTo

Tags: android, xml, svg, vector-graphics

So starting support library 25.4.0 path morphing is now possible on Android prior to 5.0.
But animated vectors now seem to require `valueFrom` and `valueTo`. I have this `objectAnimator` and don't know what those values should be as the code worked without them.

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="250"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:pathData="M 12.0,15.0 c 0.0,-1.0 0.0,-5.33333 0.0,-6.0"
    android:propertyXName="translateX"
    android:propertyYName="translateY"/>
```

Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: imho this is an animator that animates your view x and y positions over the curve specified by pathData - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html ObjectAnimator ofFloat (T target, 
                Property<T, Float> xProperty, 
                Property<T, Float> yProperty, 
                Path path)

Comment: @pskink and what should the `from` and `to` be? I don't actually know how to edit these, I used some pre made ones.

Comment: The snippet you have posted defines *motion along a path* - not path morphing.  That's probably why you are confused about how to convert it.